# unspecified ouput using inline function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, inline, unspecified-behavior

I was playing with code to understand internal and external linkage in c++.I came up with the code whose out seems to vary depending on the sequence in which it is linked.

**test1.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
inline int c()
{
     static int p=0;
     p++;
     return p;
}
void a()
{
     cout<<"\nIn function a() , c = "<<c();
}
```

**test2.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

inline int c()
{
    static int p=12;
    p++;
    return p;
}

void b()
{
       cout<<"\nIn function b() , c = "<<c();
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void a();
void b();
int c();

int main()
{
   b();
   a();
   a();
   b();
   cout<<"\nIn function main() = , c "<< c();
   cout<<"\n";
}
```

**output 1 :-**

```
when compiles as follows :- 

bash#>g++ -c test1.cpp
bash#>g++ -c test2.cpp
bash#>g++ -c driver.cpp

bash#>g++ -o out driver.o test1.o test2.o
bash#>./out

In function b() , c = 1
In function a() ,  c = 2
In function a() ,  c = 3
In function b() , c = 4
IN main() , c = 5
```

In above output , compiler is considering c() defined in test1.cpp

**output 2:-**
changing sequence of test1.o and test2.o while linking.

```
bash#>g++ -o out driver.o test2.o test1.o

In function b() , c = 13
In function a() ,  c = 14
In function a() ,  c = 15 
In function b() , c = 16
IN main() , c = 17
```

In above output , compiler is considering c() defined in test2.cpp

I was perplexed when i made minor changes in the code , which are as follows :-

1) if I do not call c() in function a() [test1.cpp] and c() in funciton b()[test2.cpp]

```
//test1.cpp changes
void a()
{
   cout<<"\nIn function a() , c = "; // not calling c()
}

//test2.cpp changes
void b()
{
    cout<<"\nIn function b() , c = "; // not calling c()
}
```

I get following error while linking :-

```
bash#>g++ -o out driver.o test1.o test2.o
driver.o: In function `main':
driver.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `c()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

2) If i call c() in any one of the file i.e either in test1.cpp or in test2.cpp , then i wont get linker error.

Could anyone please help me in understanding this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid linker issues, move your `inline` functions to the header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior because it violates the One Definition Rule. Two different translation units are defining a function with same name and signature, but with different bodies.

Per paragraph 3.2/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Given
>   such an entity named `D` **defined in more than one translation unit**, then
>
> — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
>
> [...]

Your program is also ill-formed because function `c()` is declared as `inline` in `test1.cpp` and `test2.cpp`, but not in `driver.cpp`. Per paragraph 7.1.2/4

> [...] If a function with external linkage is
>   declared `inline` in one translation unit, it shall be declared `inline` in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required. [...]

The "*no diagnostic is required*" bit means that the compiler (or linker) may or may not report an error for a violation of this rule. That means you have to be very careful to break it.

Comment: And he has an inline function that not in all TUs is declared `inline` as-well. +1

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I missed that, thank you for mentioning. I'm going to edit

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But what is the reason for point(2) in my post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But what is the reason for point(1) and point(2) in my post.
why compiler throws error when i don't call c() in function a() and in function b().
whereas it does not throws error if i call c() in either function a() or in function b()

Comment: @user1057741: That's because the program is ill-formed and the compiler/linker is not required to tell you for a violation of this rule. So it may produce an error or not. The conclusion is: "Just don't do that". If a function is declared as `inline` in one translation unit, it must declare `inline` in *all* translation units

Comment: @AndyProwl: yes even when i made inline in all translation unit ...i am getting same problem.
code snippet is more for understanding purpose...i wont do it when i will be working on a project.

Comment: @user1057741: It's still undefined behavior, since the two functions do not have the same definition (see my answer)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thanks for c++ standard details ...now could you please tell where from where i can refer c++ standard (book,link ..anything will e hepfull)

Comment: @user1057741: [This](http://isocpp.org/) is the official C++ website, which also contains a link to the most recent draft (on the left, below the picture of Bjarne)

Comment: Below is the explanation of my post..he executed similar program 

http://winfred-lu.blogspot.in/2009/11/understand-weak-symbols-by-examples.html